# Get Episerver Property though Episerver API/Database query

Tags: database, api, report, episerver

I have an episerver site with almost all the blocks having a common Image property as given below:

```
[Display(GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content, Name = "Image", Description = "This is description link for alt", Order = 30)]
[UIHint(UIHint.Image)]
public virtual ContentReference Image { get; set; }
```

This property is used throughout the application. I need to generate a report to get all the references where the `Description` is empty.
Is there a way to get the above using episerver api or database query?
This is a new area for me & so any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about the "Description" in the Display decoration? If so, that description is only for the editing UI. If you're trying to get a report of all images without an "alt" attribute value, that should be part of a different property, commonly stored on the actual ImageData model.

Comment: I think there's some confusion about the `Description` property on the `Display` attribute? It is only intended to describe to a web editor, i.e. Episerver user, what the `Image` property does. It's just an optional way to add some additional information to the UI to complement the `Name`.

It's not Episerver-specific, but rather standard .NET annotation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.description?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I do understand that the display attribute is nothing but an attribute pertaining to the .net standard annotation.But since i am working on the website remediation ,i need to find out if it is available throughout the site or is it missing in places.I would like to know where these properties are stored within the episerver tables.One way is to manually do that but is there any episerver api to get them or through database queries.

Comment: If you need metadata about content types (including their properties), you can get the implementation of `IContentTypeRepository` through `ServiceLocator`. It gives you access to all content types.

Comment: Thanks Ted. Your inputs helped me get all the images from Media folder along with their complete url. For Images under content assets, is there any way in the system to edit or remove those files?